# js function calling an api doesn't respond with expected values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to collect all the market pairs from a crypto exchange using its API, but I'm not sure how to select the proper line in the JSON object as it does not seem to work.

the api : https://ftx.com/api/markets

my code :
requests.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import parsers from './parsers';


async function ftxMarkets() {
    const ftxResponse = await axios.get('https://ftx.com/api/markets');
    return parsers.ftxMarkets(ftxResponse.data);
}
```

parsers.js

```
function ftxMarkets(data) {
    const [ftxMarketPairs] = data;
    let ftxPairs = data.map(d => d.name );
    console.log(ftxPairs);

};
```

I'm not sure about `d.name` in the parsers.js file, but I tried with another exchange with the same code, changing just that part and it worked, so I guess that's where the problem comes from, although can't be sure and I don't know by what to replace it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran the api call and after looking at the response I see a result key with the list of all crypto data. So I am guessing it'll work if you call the parser with the result object like this

```
    return parsers.ftxMarkets(ftxResponse.result);
    // try parsers.ftxMarkets(ftxResponse.data.result) if the above one doesnt work
```

and then in the parser it should work normally

```
function ftxMarkets(data) {
    let ftxPairs = data.map(d => d.name );
    console.log(ftxPairs);
};
```

Update:

Since fxtResponse.data.result works. Your issue should be a CORS issue and to fix that there are two options.

1. CORS plugin in web browser(not recommended in production)
2. Proxy it through a server. By requesting the resource through a proxy - The simplest way, what you can do is, write a small node server (or if you already have a back-end associate it with your front-end you can use it) which does the request for the 3rd party API and sends back the response. And in that server response now you can allow cross-origin header.

For 2 If you already have a nodeJs server. You can use CORs Npm package and call the third party api from the server and serve the request to the front end with CORS enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Vikrant ! Unfortunately I tried both lines and neither worked for me.

Comment: Hey @JamesChen. I tried it in my app. fxtResponse.data.result works as expected. I think you're getting a CORs error in your app. You can check if a CORs error is happening by looking at the console tab in developer options. Something like this error should be present "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ftx.com/api/markets' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource". I'll update my answer to accomodate this.

Comment: Thanks for your help !